# global variables in Python using in multiple routes/pages

Tags: python, flask, routes, global-variables

Hi I'm wondering if it's possible to use a global variable between routes (I'm using flask)

Basically I have one page/route that loads multiple choice questions and stores the correct answer in a variable answer, and I want another route to use that answer variable.

I tried creating a global variable and then assigning it to the value of the answer inside the first route, but I can't get it to work.

Here's the relevant code --

```
global glob_answer
glob_answer = "Answer"    # initialized to this value for testing (I get nothing)

@app.route('/quiz')
def quiz():
    cursor = g.conn.execute("select actor_name, categ, a_name, year, title from win_actor order by random() limit 1")

    c_names  = []
    category = ""
    alias    = ""
    year     = ""
    title    = ""
    for name in cursor:
        c_names.append(name[0]) # can also be accessed using result[0]

#SETTING GLOBAL VARIABLE EQUAL TO ANSWER
        answer  = name[0]
        glob_answer = answer
        category = name[1]
        year     = str(name[3])
        title    = name[4]
        cursor2 = g.conn.execute("select alias from awards where a_name = " + "'" + name[2] + "'" + " limit 1")
        for columns in cursor2:
            alias = columns[0]
        cursor2.close()
    cursor.close()
    cursor = g.conn.execute("select * from actor limit 4")
    for name in cursor:
        if name[0] not in c_names:
            c_names.append(name[0]) # can also be accessed using result[0]
    cursor.close()
    shuffle(c_names)
    context = dict(data = c_names, categ = category, award_name = alias, year = year, title = title, answer = answer)
    return render_template("quiz.html", **context)

#Second Route
@app.route('/answer')
def answer():
#TRYING TO PASS VALUE TO NEW LOCAL VARIABLE
    global glob_answer 
    answer = glob_answer   
    return render_template("answer.html")
```

When I display the 'answer' variable in my html, nothing shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to send unique ID of your question to `answer` route and then select answer from DB and render it in template:

```
@app.route('/answer/<question_id>')
def answer(question_id):
    # Here you need to select answer from database
    answer = get_answer(question_id)   
    return render_template("answer.html")
```

Comment: Do you mean to have the questions as a part of the database as well as the answers? At the moment I don't actually have the questions in a database -- they are just hard coded into the html using the the fields from the database.

Comment: That's right. For example, you can store your's questions in database, then your's `quiz` route will select questions and render it, and then you can check correct answer by sending ajax request to `answer` route with question_id